# Get time difference between two tables only for rows with the same 'id' - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I ned to ged time difference between tableA and tableB for rows with the same id. Therefore id 10 and 11.

```
tableA:

id  book  scandate
----------------------
10  AA    '2021-01-15 08:52:05'
11  BB    '2021-01-15 08:55:15'
12  CC    '2021-01-15 08:56:23'
13  DD    '2021-01-15 09:01:02'

tableB:

id  book  scandate
----------------------
10  AA    '2021-01-15 08:52:15'
11  BB    '2021-01-15 08:55:28'
14  EE    '2021-01-15 08:56:23'
15  FF    '2021-01-15 09:01:02'
```

How can I do that? I know I can use timediff function but I dont know how to fetch wanted data into given function.

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that I need average value for timediff results.

```
select AVG(T.scandateDiff) from (
select tableA.id, tableA.book, tableA.scandate as scandateA, tableB.scandate as scandateB,
       timediff(tableB.scandate, tableA.scandate) as scandateDiff
from 
tableA 
join
tableB
on tableA.id = tableB.id) as T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` to combine the table and then whatever function you want for the difference:

```
select a.*, b.*,
       timediff(a.scandate, b.scandate)
from a join
     b
     on a.id = b.id
```